# SQL add all values of a group as a new value

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I would like to create from this table:

| id | att_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | G |
| 2 | R |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 3 | F |

Something like that: (there's also a timestamp column, att_2 column should be organized based on the timestamp, earlier on the left side)

| id | att_1 | att_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | G | G,R |
| 2 | R | G,R |
| 1 | A | A,B,C |
| 1 | B | A,B,C |
| 1 | C | A,B,C |
| 3 | F | F |

Comment: Lookup string_Agg function `STRING_AGG (att_1,',')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use windows function and make simple query like below:

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=16f102612fe2b1d0d40c61feb7d43f52)

```sql
select
  id,
  att_1,
  string_agg(att_1, ',') over (
    partition by id
  ) as att_2
from  test1
```

For update statement:

```sql
update test2 t2
set att_2 = t.att_2
from (
  select
    id,
    att_1,
    string_agg(att_1, ',') over (
      partition by id
    ) as att_2
  from test1
) t
where t.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Should be noted this is a one time update.

Answer (score 0):

string_Agg I believe is the fucntion you're looking for.  Some systems use List_Agg  Just depends on RDMBS... This appears to be Postgresql so I think it's string_agg.

`string_agg(Value, deliniator, order by [optional])`

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Att_1, t2.Att_2 
FROM tblName t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, STRING_AGG (att_1,',' Order by Att_2) att_2 
            FROM tblName
            GROUP BY ID) t2
 on t2.ID = t1.ID
```

--BUILDING ON THE ABOVE and assuming this is a 1 and done thing...

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.Att_1, t2.Att_2 
    FROM tblName t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, STRING_AGG (att_1,',' Order by Att_2) att_2 
                FROM tblName
                GROUP BY ID) t2
     on t2.ID = t1.ID)

UPDATE tblName ut1
SET ut1.att_2 = CTE.Att_2
FROM CTE
WHERE ut1.ID = CTE.ID;
```

-- if not one and done....

Then consider using a trigger, function based index, or computed/generated column.  While I'm confident a trigger would work; I'm unsure if a function based index or computed/generated column would as an analytic function is needed and it would need to process multiple rows.

Comment: I'm trying to update the existing table (adding att_2 to the original table), how would you manage it?

Comment: Is this one time and done?  What happens if the data changes and a new row is added such that att_2 would get a new value?  Example: a new record 3 is added with att_1 "Z" but we have ATT_2 as "F" after we're done.  Would you want the new record AND the old 3 record to both be "F,Z" now?  I ask because if this is a one time thing it's a simple update statement.  If this is a recurring situation which must be maintained as data changes; the answer is very different.

Comment: It should be noted the community generally prefers one question to one answer.  This is getting into a 2nd question and should be treated as such.